# Mongoid Geonear sort results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, geo

From my mongo console I am able to run:

```
      db.runCommand({geoNear: "coords", near: [coords], spherical: true, maxDistance: 5})
```

Everything works fine, I am getting the results sorted by which document is closest.
But when I am trying through my rails application with mongoid I am still getting results but not sorted.

```
      session = Mongoid.session('default')
      res = session.command({geoNear: "coords", near: [params[:lat].to_i, params[:lon].to_i], spherical: true, maxDistance: 5})
```

Why is that? How I can get the sorted results in my controller?
Thank you in advance.